# How do I make Hammock issue an HTTP GET

Tags: silverlight, web-services, rest, silverlight-4.0, hammock

I have a Silverlight 4.0 application that is making RESTful calls to an MVC3 application using the `Hammock API` on the client to issue the RESTful service codes.

The problem is that whether the `request.Method` is set to `WebMethod.Get` or `WebMethod.Post`, the request that is sent is a `POST`.  What am I doing wrong?

```
private IAsyncResult GetServerList()
{
    var callback = new RestCallback((restRequest, restResponse, userState) =>
                {
                    // There is some working callback code here.  Excluded for clarity.
                }
            );

    var request = new RestRequest();
    request.Method = WebMethod.Get;
    request.Path = "ServerList";
    return _restClient.BeginRequest(request, callback);
}
```

Comment: What is `RestRequest`?  Is that something you have coded or is it part of some third-party component?

Comment: RestRequest is part of the Hammock API Library

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the request type on RestClient.

```
var restClient = new RestClient
        {
            Method = WebMethod.Get
        };
```

Or from your example:

```
private IAsyncResult GetServerList()
{
    var callback = new RestCallback((restRequest, restResponse, userState) =>
            {
                // There is some working callback code here.  Excluded for clarity.
            }
    );

    var request = new RestRequest();
    request.Path = "ServerList";

    _restClient.Method = WebMethod.Get;
    return _restClient.BeginRequest(request, callback);
}
```